# How do i reverse engineer a known Cyclic Redundancy Check value?

Tags: error-handling, binary, hex, crc, cyclic

So I have problem finding the CRC value for a series of commands, I already have the CRC values for some of the commands but I need to figure out how they were calculated. After carefully going over the data stream and attempting to calculate the CRC we cannot get the known CRC value and the calculated one to match. I have never calculated a CRC before but I have read multiple papers on it and it seems easy enough, except for the fact that its not working. The manual I have says the polynomial generator is (x^8 + x^7 + X^2 + X^0) and it gives me a unique non zero value of B1 (hex). The full command is A9E40401 (hex) with a CRC of 1E (hex). The process I am currently using involves converting the data stream from hex into binary, using the LSB first rule, inserting FF(hex) into the command to detect extraneous zeros, adding 00(hex) to the end as a place holder and than performing mod2 division, and than I invert it and apply it to the data stream. Either I'm doing something wrong or I missed a step. I am assuming the polynomial I was provided is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. 
When I calculated my CRC I did every step properly except the very last step where you must perform the LSB first rule and than invert the remainder. 
I only performed the LSB first rule (thinking that's what was meant by invert).
So with a remainder of 00011101 I got the wrong CRC value (10111000). when I should have gotten 01000111.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [RevEng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/), which is for exactly this, to determine the CRC parameters from a set of examples.

Then you can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate the code.

Comment: awesome. Thank you for your valuable assistance. I hope this aids me in solving my problem. I will post my results as they come up.